# Images work on local server but not production

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, server-setup

I am working on a Magento 1.9.0 store on my local machine and I have recently pushed it out to the production server, but I am having some problems with "missing" images (they fall back to placeholder images)

- They all work flawlessly everywhere on my local MAMP machine
- On the production server they work when customers browse for the products using categories
- On the production server they work in the back end admin system
- On the production server they don't work in the search result pages
- On the production server they don't work in the individual product listing pages.

I have tried:

- Removing the cache folder
- chmod 777 /var/cache
- chmod 777 /media
- Rebuilding all indexes
- Flushing all caches via admin panel
- Reindexing everything via admin panel

I'm not sure what else I can try?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are trying to upload new image in admin side any product and check this product to frontend site then image showing or not. Can you check this?

Comment: Yes, I can upload new images via the admin side but the imported ones don't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you open image url directly in the browser? If not you need to fix the files permissions.

You can try that command in SSH (append sudo to the command maybe required)

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed my issue.

It looks like the unlimited memory limit setting that I had set up was causing the system to not be able to read the images (or upload images in the admin area)

I have adjusted this to a 2048M limit and it now seems to be working correctly.